# Devise Landing Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I am using Rails 4 and wanting to have a landing page whereby the users can elect to either sign in or sign up. The issue I am having at present is that the routes keep directing me back to the sign_in.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/index'

  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :people
```

HomeController

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end
end
```

PeopleController

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_person!

  respond_to :html
```

Terminal Output

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-17 22:28:51 +1100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro tip: Get rid of the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controllers, and use the [following routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb):

```
  #config/routes.rb
  authenticated :user do
    root 'home#dashboard', as: :root #-> if user is logged in
    resources :controller #-> ONLY available for logged in users
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root 'home#index', as: :unauthenticated #-> if user is not logged in
  end
```

If the user is authenticated, the `authenticated` routes will be presented, if not the `unauthenticated` routes will show.

The important thing to note is that `authenticated :user` means that those routes will *only* be available when the user is logged in. `authenticate :user` will allow the user to view the routes if not logged in, but will be redirected to the `sign in` page as you have currently.

Comment: so i have implemented the above, and it appears to be displaying me a landing page, though if i navigate to a page prior to login in it tells me the route doesn't exist

Comment: devise_for :people

  authenticated :user do
    root 'home#dashboard', as: :root #-> if user is logged in
    #-> ONLY available for logged in users
    resources :people
    resources :venues
    resources :store_configs
    resources :orders
    resources :menu_items
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root 'home#index', as: :unauthenticated #-> if user is not logged in
  end